# `select regexp_replace(<column>, '\s+', ' ')` wants explicit type cast, but how?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

The query:

```
update enquiry_address_data  
set address_line_1 = upper(regexp_replace(btrim(address_line_1), '\s+', ' '));
```

returns

```
ERROR: function regexp_replace(text, "unknown", "unknown") does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.
```

I added explicit type casts like so:

```
update enquiry_address_data  
set address_line_1 = upper(regexp_replace(btrim(address_line_1), '\s+' :: text, ' ' :: text));
```

still I get

```
ERROR: function regexp_replace(text, character varying, character varying) does not exist
Hint: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.
```

I'm using PostgreSql 9.3 JDBC driver connected to an Amazon RedShift instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Redshift doesn't have `regexp_replace`, it's cut down fork of an old PostgreSQL version with a bunch of added stuff.

See the Redshift documentation. See also `\df pg_catalog.*` or `\df pg_catalog.*regexp*`.

Answer (score 2):

`regexp_replace` is one of many [unsupported PostgreSQL functions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_unsupported-postgresql-functions.html) in redshift.

One by one, those functions are added - take a look at a [documentation history](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/doc-history.html).

Comment: Gee, it'd be nice if Amazon would contribute a few of the less Redshift/ParAccel and Amazon AWS-specific changes back as patches to mainline Pg.